# Proof that $\mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb C$

Tags: general-topology

Context: I am self-studying introductory topology by following some videos. There was an exercise showing that $\mathbb Z$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ and I'm curious if something similar can be shown for $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb C$.

It seems that $\mathbb R$ should be closed in $\mathbb C$, but I am having trouble convincing myself that my proof is sufficiently rigorous.

Some of my concerns:

1. Is the first step defining $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ too much of a leap of faith?
2. Have I established all the needed criteria for the set $\mathbb C^+$ to be open at the end?
3. Are there any mistakes or inconsistencies, especially with the inequality manipulations?
4. I'm not really satisfied skipping over the argument for $\mathbb C^-$, though I suspect that the proof can be finished in a more "elegant" manner, maybe by introducing some kind of isomorphism between the two sets. But, I'm not 100% sure what the needed criteria are that I need to establish.

I am sure there is a significantly faster route to prove this as well, which I'd be happy to see.

Here is what I have so far:

---

By definition, a closed set is closed if and only if its complement is open. So, it should suffice to show that $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ is open.

$\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ may be expressed as the union of $\mathbb C^+$ and $\mathbb C^-$, where

$\mathbb C^+ = \{z \in \mathbb C \mid \Im(z)>0\}$, and

$\mathbb C^- = \{z \in \mathbb C \mid \Im(z)<0\}$.

Let $z$ be some arbitrary point in $\mathbb C^+$, and let $\epsilon$ be some number such that $0 < \epsilon < \Im(z)$. Then we consider the open ball $B_\epsilon (z)$ defined by

$B_\epsilon (z)=\{w \in \mathbb C \mid |w-z| < \epsilon\}$.

For all $w \in B_\epsilon (z)$, the inequality $|w-z| < \epsilon$ holds, which also implies that $|z-w| < \epsilon$. By the reverse triangle inequality for complex numbers, we have

$\implies \epsilon > |z-w| \geq ||z|-|w|| \geq ||\Im(z)|-|\Im(w)||$

As we have taken $z$ to be an element of $\mathbb C^+$, $\Im(z)$ is positive by definition, so we may omit the absolute value.

$\implies |\Im(z)-|\Im(w)|| < \epsilon $

$\implies -\epsilon < \Im(z)-|\Im(w)| < \epsilon $

$\implies \Im(z)-|\Im(w)| < \epsilon $

$\implies |\Im(w)| > \Im(z) - \epsilon$

From the above inequality, we can consider two cases:

$\Im(w) < -\Im(z) + \epsilon$ (Case 1), or

$\Im(w) > \Im(z) - \epsilon$ (Case 2).

The definition $0 < \epsilon < \Im(z)$ implies that $\Im(z) - \epsilon > 0$, and, equivalently, $-\Im(z) + \epsilon < 0$. This, together with case 1, would imply that

$\implies \Im(w) < 0$.

However, this is a contradiction, because we know of at least one point in $B_\epsilon (z)$, namely $z$ itself, whose imaginary part is strictly positive.

Thus, we can consider Case 2, which implies

$\implies \Im(w) > 0$.

From this we can conclude that the ball $B_\epsilon (z)$ is a subset of $\mathbb C^+$. Consequently, for any point $z \in \mathbb C^+$ we can find a neighborhood (the ball $B_\epsilon (z)$) consisting of points also strictly within $\mathbb C^+$. Thus, $\mathbb C^+$ is open.

A nearly identical argument can be applied to $\mathbb C^-$ showing that $\mathbb C^-$ is also open.

Since $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ is a union of open sets, $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ is open, thus $\mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Hint : $Im(z)$ is a continuous function so the preimage of a closed set is closed.

Comment: To elaborate David's comment, note that $| \operatorname{im} z_1 - \operatorname{im} z_2| \le |z_1-z_2|$ so $\operatorname{im} $ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: 1. No this isn't a leap of faith! You can try to show $C \setminus R = C^+ \cup C^-$ yourself, it's not that hard.

2. Your argument that it is a contradiction for every $w$ is false. (Yes, it's a contradiction for at least some $w$, like $z$, but not for all).

3. in general the inequeliteis are good

4. it's quite obvious that the proof for $C^-$ should be analogous, those things will become more clear as you progress in maths.
 The reason the question is closed is because an equivalent one was asked elsewhere, but that one excludes your concerns. Please let me know if any questions!!

Comment: to add to 2.: You have to show $B_\epsilon (z) \subseteq C^+$, this will be true (as you can conclude from a drawing). So how to you prove it? Maybe try to show first that $|\text{im} \, z - \text{im} \, w| \leq |z - w|$ ...

Comment: Another alternative method is the limit characterization of a closed set, aka, a set is closed iff (for any sequence in the set it holds that if it converges, then the limit is included in the set). So if $(z_n)$ is an arbitrary real sequence with a limit ($z$) in $C$, try to show that $z$ must be real.

Comment: @NeckverseHerdman Thanks for your answers! I realized that the proof can be simplified significantly by letting $\epsilon=\Im(z)/2$, in which case $\Im(w) > 0$ follows almost immediately.